# How to debug GKE internal network issue?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

UPDATE 1:
Some more logs from api-servers:
https://gist.github.com/nvcnvn/47df8798e798637386f6e0777d869d4f

---

This question is more about debugging method for current GKE but welcome for solution.
We're using GKE version `1.22.3-gke.1500` with following configuration:
[image]

We recently facing issue that commands like `kubectl logs` and `exec` doesn't work, deleting a namespace taking forever.
Checking some service inside the cluster, it seem for some reason some network operation just randomly failed. For example `metric-server` keep crashing with these error logs:

```
message: "pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.10/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1.Node: failed to list *v1.Node: Get "https://10.97.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes?resourceVersion=387681528": net/http: TLS handshake timeout"
```

HTTP request timeout also:

```
unable to fully scrape metrics: unable to fully scrape metrics from node gke-staging-n2d-standard-8-78c35b3a-6h16: unable to fetch metrics from node gke-staging-n2d-standard-8-78c35b3a-6h16: Get "http://10.148.15.217:10255/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true": context deadline exceeded
```

and I also try to restart (by kubectl delete) most of the pod in this list:

```
kubectl get pod
NAME                                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
event-exporter-gke-5479fd58c8-snq26                   2/2     Running   0               4d7h
fluentbit-gke-gbs2g                                   2/2     Running   0               4d7h
fluentbit-gke-knz2p                                   2/2     Running   0               85m
fluentbit-gke-ljw8h                                   2/2     Running   0               30h
gke-metadata-server-dtnvh                             1/1     Running   0               4d7h
gke-metadata-server-f2bqw                             1/1     Running   0               30h
gke-metadata-server-kzcv6                             1/1     Running   0               85m
gke-metrics-agent-4g56c                               1/1     Running   12 (3h6m ago)   4d7h
gke-metrics-agent-hnrll                               1/1     Running   13 (13h ago)    30h
gke-metrics-agent-xdbrw                               1/1     Running   0               85m
konnectivity-agent-87bc84bb7-g9nd6                    1/1     Running   0               2m59s
konnectivity-agent-87bc84bb7-rkhhh                    1/1     Running   0               3m51s
konnectivity-agent-87bc84bb7-x7pk4                    1/1     Running   0               3m50s
konnectivity-agent-autoscaler-698b6d8768-297mh        1/1     Running   0               83m
kube-dns-77d9986bd5-2m8g4                             4/4     Running   0               3h24m
kube-dns-77d9986bd5-z4j62                             4/4     Running   0               3h24m
kube-dns-autoscaler-f4d55555-dmvpq                    1/1     Running   0               83m
kube-proxy-gke-staging-n2d-standard-8-78c35b3a-8299   1/1     Running   0               11s
kube-proxy-gke-staging-n2d-standard-8-78c35b3a-fp5u   1/1     Running   0               11s
kube-proxy-gke-staging-n2d-standard-8-78c35b3a-rkdp   1/1     Running   0               11s
l7-default-backend-7db896cb4-mvptg                    1/1     Running   0               83m
metrics-server-v0.4.4-fd9886cc5-tcscj                 2/2     Running   82              33h
netd-5vpmc                                            1/1     Running   0               30h
netd-bhq64                                            1/1     Running   0               85m
netd-n6jmc                                            1/1     Running   0               4d7h
```

Some logs from metrics server
https://gist.github.com/nvcnvn/b77eb02705385889961aca33f0f841c7

Comment: This all sounds like issues reaching the control plane. I would ask where you are running commands from, but since the metrics explorer is also suffering the issue, I would recommend reaching out to Google for support since the control plane is fully managed by them.

Comment: Ah yep, this issue is really difficult for me because I don't know if possible to get any logs or metrics from the control plane.

Comment: Btw I run the command from GCP console.

Comment: As I can see you are using GKE v. 1.22.3-gke.1500 which is a Rapid channel. `Rapid channel is offered on an early access basis for customers who want to test new releases before they are qualified for production use or general availability.` Did you try to use the older version from the `Regular` channel? I can also see that some of your pods have a few days and others like `konnectivity` are 2 or 3 mins, are you scaling your cluster to 0 and then scaling up? Does this issue occur from time to time or is it's whole time?

Comment: Could you share logs of `kubectl logs metrics-server-v0.4.4-fd9886cc5-tcscj -n kube-system -c metrics-server` or error you are getting when you try to use this command? Those 82 restarts are disturbing. Did you try to check GKE logs from one of the ways described [here](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/using-logs)?

Comment: Actually I face that issue on Regular channel and face the issue, I tried to upgrade to newest version to see if it fix.

Comment: @PjoterS updated the question with more logs. I'm able to get logs when the issue not happen. Also logs still collected by stackdriver during that time.

Comment: Could you provide more details on how you deployed, upgraded your env? I'd like to replicate this on my test env. You mention you've upgraded your cluster. You have upgraded master or nodes also? You are using workload identity, did you also enable it on your nodepool? Your `staging` network, did you create any rules which might interrupt connectivity? If you would create a fresh GKE cluster in your `staging` and `default` network, you also get the same errors on both GKE clusters? Between 1.21 and 1.22 there were some API changes so it might be the reason.

Comment: I will try to reproduce the issue also but it not the easy task for us... Network side I can't recall anything special (we disable network policy as the image). Workload Identity seem working normal (we use it to access GCP services and all the containers can work just fine).

Comment: I tried a few scenarios to replicate your issue but no luck. Did you have time to replicate this behavior?

Comment: I'm able to replicate the issue with a new cluster by replicate exactly what we have on staging...but I guess it doesn't help much.

Comment: Is it possible to provide your steps to get this issue (without private/sensitive information)? I tried a few times but I am not able to replicate this on my environment.

Comment: @PjoterS I'm trying to provide that but the process take quite long, our env sometime having few hundreds of pod. Maybe it worth to mention that we're using https://www.vcluster.com/ - at first I think it related but maybe not.

Comment: One more thing, the cluster that have issue have cluster auto scaling enabled and add/remove few nodes every 1-2 hours.

Comment: Are you using preemptible nodes? I am still not able to replicate this issue on my env. Could you tell more about this vcluster configuration?

Comment: No, we just use normal nodes. Our vcluster usage just follow the quick start, each vcluster have 1 replicaset of 3 pod Elastic search, 3 pod of NATS.io, 1 simple Postgres and 10 Golang applications pod.

Comment: Ah also we have VerticalPodAutoscaler mode Off for the 10 services, maybe it related to metric servers. I will try to replicate exactly with some open source this weekend. Sry that I'm unable to give you something can be easier to reproduce, but since this block our devs so I need to workaround first

Comment: @nvcnvn any updates?

Comment: @PjoterS sorry, I missed you reply, actually I surrender to reproduce the issue with some simple open sources deployment, but I pretty sure its something related to konnectivity.

Answer (score 0):

if you cannot use kubectl to get info from your cluster, can you try to access them by using their restfull api
http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/understanding-k8s-api-part-2/
try to delete "metric-server" pods or get logs from it using podman or curl command.